# PC Blue Screen STOP: 09C and 101

Tags: windows-7, cpu, bluescreenview

I have this PC workstation (Dell Precision T5500 from ~2010; Win7). It recently started to show blue screens every time I tried to boot it.

The 'STOP:101' screen occurs during the booting of Windows. Of the a few trials, the 'physical memory dumping' in 'STOP:101' couldn't even finish.

This computer has been used a media-editing workstation for many years (has a G-RAID 8TB from ~2012), and I almost never turned it off.

I did a little research online but couldn't figure out the best solution.
For example: No new hardware was added any recently; never did CPU overlocking or changing BIOS settings. Since I couldn't start the operation system, I can't do any adjustments within.

Here are a few posts where people discussed these STOPs, similar problems but with different specifics:
[link1](https://appuals.com/fix-a-clock-interrupt-was-not-received-on-a-secondary-processor-within-the-allocated-time-interval/)
[link2](https://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/348592-bsod-windows-7-startup-error-0x0000009c.html)
[link3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bsod-stop-0x0000009c/a9d35841-594d-4221-8713-4f832d050c49)
[link4](https://www.icare-recovery.com/howto/fix-blue-screen-stop-0x0000009c-machine-check-exception.html)

Any advice would be very appreciated!

P.S. also my first time posting. If there is a better place to ask this question I'd happily transfer there.

[STOP 101 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ljb7.jpg)

[STOP 09C screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEHZM.jpg)

Comment: This is a hardware error and could be the disk drive. Get the computer manufacturer's or disk manufacturer's hardware diagnostic app and test the hardware and particularly the drive.